# Is it possible to dispatch events on regular objects (not DOM ones)?

Tags: javascript, events, dom, filereader, dispatch

I just found out that FileReader dispatches events just as if it was a DOM element. Is it? I wonder if it's possible to create an object similar to FileReader, which doesn't have a representation in HTML/XML structure, but can dispatch events?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`FileReader` has methods like `addEventHandler` because it is [defined](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#dfn-filereader) to implement the [`EventTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/EventTarget) interface. `EventTarget` is defined by the [DOM Events](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/) spec but you don't need to be a DOM object to implement it. `window`, `XMLHttpRequest` and `FileReader` are other Browser Object Model objects that implement `EventTarget`.

Unfortunately there's no easy way to piggyback on the browser's native implementation of event targets... you could try inheriting from a browser object by using one as a `prototype` property, but that's very unreliable in general. However it is not too difficult to write code to implement all the methods yourself in plain JavaScript:

```
function CustomEventTarget() { this._init(); }

CustomEventTarget.prototype._init= function() {
    this._registrations= {};
};
CustomEventTarget.prototype._getListeners= function(type, useCapture) {
    var captype= (useCapture? '1' : '0')+type;
    if (!(captype in this._registrations))
        this._registrations[captype]= [];
    return this._registrations[captype];
};

CustomEventTarget.prototype.addEventListener= function(type, listener, useCapture) {
    var listeners= this._getListeners(type, useCapture);
    var ix= listeners.indexOf(listener);
    if (ix===-1)
        listeners.push(listener);
};

CustomEventTarget.prototype.removeEventListener= function(type, listener, useCapture) {
    var listeners= this._getListeners(type, useCapture);
    var ix= listeners.indexOf(listener);
    if (ix!==-1)
        listeners.splice(ix, 1);
};

CustomEventTarget.prototype.dispatchEvent= function(evt) {
    var listeners= this._getListeners(evt.type, false).slice();
    for (var i= 0; i<listeners.length; i++)
        listeners[i].call(this, evt);
    return !evt.defaultPrevented;
};
```

Caution: the above code is off the top of my head and untested, but may work. However it has limitations like only supporting the `dispatchEvent` return value if the `Event` object supports the DOM Level 3 `defaultPrevented` property, and no support for DOM Level 3 `stopImmediatePropagation()` (which is impossible to implement unless you rely on your own Event object that exposes a property for it). Also there's no implementation of hierarchy or capture/bubbling.

So IMO: you don't gain much by trying to write code that participates in the DOM Events model. For plain-JS callback work I'd just go with your own ad hoc implementation of listener-lists.

Comment: I got my own event model - a function that binds handlers to an "event types", storing them in a hash, and a function that triggers "events" on objects that inherit this model (and some other utility methods). Do you say that default event model doesn't have any valuable benefit over mine?

Comment: Yeah, the benefits are quite small I'd say—you can't actually be 100% interoperable with other implementations of `Event` due to not being able to reliably read whether `preventDefault`/`stopPropagation`/`stopImmediatePropagation` have been called. So the only benefit is the familiarity of the DOM Events interface... but it's arguably quite a clunky interface.

Comment: I've stumbled upon this one: http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#interface-CustomEvent, where W3C recommends it for creating application-specific event types. As far as I see not yet widely supported, but it seems that's where the whole thing is heading.

Comment: Yeah,though currently only Opera supports it. And it doesn't really give you that much, only a `detail` property, which is handy in stricter languages like Java, but of limited use in JS where you can put any arbitrary properties on your objects anyway.

Comment: Hi @bobince.  The difference between native event handlers and this method, which is used by every implementation I've seen (including my own), is that native handlers run in a separate execution context from the dispatcher.  Whereas with this method, a failure in one handler will prevent all subsequent handlers from running.  [This post from 2009](http://dean.edwards.name/weblog/2009/03/callbacks-vs-events/) got me thinking about it, although I think the proposed "hybrid" solution may be a bit heavyweight for general use.  Thought you'd find it interesting.

Answer (score 4):

[bobince has the right idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6635854/2154092), but his code is just an example.  For an actual battle-tested implementation, [Mr. Doob has one that he uses in three.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/eventdispatcher.js).

Comment: If you aren't as concerned with emulating the ECMAScript API, also consider [signals](http://millermedeiros.github.com/js-signals/) and [bacon](https://github.com/raimohanska/bacon.js).

Answer (score 1):

jQuery can dispatch events from regular objects. [Here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/skibulk/00vjn9fk/).

```
function MyClass() {
    $(this).on("MyEvent", function(event) {
        console.log(event);
    });

    $(this).trigger("MyEvent");
}

var instance = new MyClass();
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume it's javascript ; normally any object that can get a reference to a DOM element should be able to dispatch an event using the element.dispatchEvent function ; see :

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createEvent

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.dispatchEvent

Comment: Yes, came here from these pages. I mean that FileReader doesn't seem to be related to any DOM element, or have a reference to it. But at the same time it has a dispatchEvent method in itself and can dispatch events (DOM events I guess). A bit confusing isn't it? I wondered if there was a way to create an object with similar properties.

Comment: Well I don't have any implementation of FileReader around hand, so it's only speculation, but if the DOM element was just kept internally as a private method, and the dispatchEvent of the FileReader was just forwarding the call to the dispatchEvent of the internal DOM element, how would we know ?

Comment: What do you mean by internal DOM element? Is there a real world term like this or are you speculating again? :) I guess if there were any internal DOM elements, then FileReader wouldn't need to forward anything. It could itself be the one.

Comment: Oh sure, I don't know about FileReader, since i guess it's part of the browser it can be implemented any way. I was just thinking : if you wanted to have a custom class of yours with the same interface and apparent behavior, all you would have to do would be to have a private propery of your object be a DOM element (that's what I meant by 'internal'), and use it to dispatch element (minus some potential issues with the currentTarget property of the dispatched event).