# how to dispatchEvent for a custom object in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, event-listener, dispatchevent

Creating a wrapper for video element.

```
function YMplayer() {
    this.video = document.getElementById("video"); /* video object */
    this.addEvents();
}

YMplayer.prototype.addEvents = function () {
    var obj = this.video;
    var events = ["load","click"];

    if (obj) {
        if (obj.addEventListener) {
            for (var i in events) {
                obj.addEventListener(i, this.dispatch(i), false);
            }
        } else if (obj.attachEvent) {
            for (var j in events) {
                obj.attachEvent("on" + j, this.dispatch(j));
            }
        }
    }

};

/* Method to dispatch the events */

YMplayer.prototype.dispatch = function (evt) {
    var evtt = document.createEvent("Events");
    evtt.initEvent(evt, true, false);
    document.dispatchEvent(evtt); /* working fine */
};

var YP = new YMplayer();
```

but i want to dispatch events from the above `YMplayer` object.

need a workaround for access addeventlistener for the instance of `YMplayer`. something like

```
YP.addEventListener("load",callback);
```

Comment: I've found couple helpful answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6635138/is-it-possible-to-dispatch-events-on-regular-objects-not-dom-ones/6635854#6635854

Answer (score 6):

You can't use Javascript events on objects, only on elements.

A solution would be to manually implement a simple 'events system', for example using an `.on` method (similar to jQuery) and storing the function that gets passed to it in your object, and then call that function when you need to fire the 'event'.

Example:

```
object.prototype.onEvent = function(handler) {
    this.eventHandler = handler;
};

// To bind the event:
instance.onEvent(function(event){
    console.log(event);
});

// When it's time to fire the event, in your object:
this.eventHandler(eventData);
```

Note: written from scratch and not tested, but I implemented something similar not too long ago and the basic idea works pretty well.

I hope my answer helps.